# Looking for a word that means someone's likelihood to take things literally

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word that means a person's ability to take things literally.

Much like how persuade would be persuasibility.

Example Sentence: "Her ___ is high. She takes things too literally"

Edit: I want a word that's only tied to a person's ability to interpret things literally. Not a word that's tied to their capacity to trust.

Comment: [**literalism**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/literalism) - *the disposition to take words and statements in their literal sense*.

Answer (score 0):

A frustrating question. She is unquestioning, credulous, uncritical, literal, over-literal, trusting, and naive. All these are easily checked in dictionaries and I do not tediously repeat definitions here.

But all these are adjectives, and you seem to ask for a noun. Weirdly, I find no appropriate noun to correspond to any of these adjectives.

*Naivety* is too wide a term, going well beyond the literate aspect you want. *gullibity* is a closely related term but is too strongly associated with being purposefully misled or deceived, so does not quite fit your specification.

Perhaps others will find a noun.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible you're thinking of ***[gullibility](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/gullible)***, a tendency to trust whatever you're told, or easily duped. Definition at TFD.

Comment: Not gullibility. It's more like interpreting things literally rather than trusting someone easily.